# Magento - If you have 2 onepagecheckouts extensions which one will magento use?

Tags: magento-1.6

I have a problem with IWD onepagecheckout it does not get activted.

I suspect that the cause is another extension that overwrites it.

There are also installed `WEB-AND-PEOPLE` one page checkout and it works fine with it is activted. But if IWD is activated as one page checkout nothing happens...

Comment: Do you deactivate the WEB-AND-PEOPLE module? And if you do, do you do it by setting its module config <active> tag to `false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, these extensions try to rewrite the OnepageController in Mage_Checkout.

Because controller rewrites cannot easily be ordered (and each plugin probably believes it to be the only plugin you'll ever have installed on your store) you will have to disable the old one entirely. Do not (I **repeat do not**) attempt to "disable module output" from the `System > Configuration > Advanced` panel.

Instead, navigate to `app/etc/modules` and remove the offending file's XML definition. In your case it's likely to be `WP_OnePageCheckout.xml`.

Comment: Magento should create a notice for this, when it happens and a guide to solve it..

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to completely remove / disable the currently active extension at a lower level.  You can either disable it in its xml (app/etc/modules/Developer_Extensionname.xml), or remove its files entirely.

This should provide a bit more technical detail:

Class rewrites aren't ever dynamic.  That means that even if your extension is disabled via a dropdown in the module's config section it is probably still rewriting then checking its config to see that its disabled (before the other module has a chance to rewrite and run).